# Knockout: Mapping/binding JSON issue

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

i'm trying a basic hello work example getting json, auto mapping it and then binding to an observable, I'm sure i'm getting something basic wrong.

JSON returned from ajax call

```
"{\"Content\":\"hello world\"}"
```

JS

```
function ViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.message = ko.observable();

$.getJSON("/home/getmessage", function (response) {
    var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJSON(response);
    self.message(mapped.Content);
});
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I'm getting the following in place of 'hello world' that i was expecting

```
function c(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!c.equalityComparer||!c.equalityComparer(d,arguments[0]))c.I(),d=arguments[0],c.H();return this}a.U.La(c);return d}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted, I had overlooked the fact ko.mapping returns observables so you have to call them as a function to get their value.

```
function viewModel() {
var self = this;

self.content = ko.observable();

$.getJSON("/home/getmessage", function (response) {
    var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJSON(response);
    self.content(mapped.Content());
});
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel);
```